# Preact + TypeScript won't allow me to directly call the h function instead of using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, preact

Please see this minimum example code:

```
import { FunctionalComponent, h } from 'preact';

const Text: FunctionalComponent = () => {
    const tag = 'div'
    const props = {}
    const children = 'I am children'

    return (
        h(tag, props, children)
    )
}
```

[image]

It says: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof h' has no compatible call signatures.`

If I directly use JSX, it will be fine:

[image]

How can I directly use the `h` function?

Comment: [declaration seems to be present](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/blob/7fe6f21aff0fd2b83dd5a53d1cef35a51a725e5f/src/index.d.ts#L153).

Comment: As Avin said, there is an `index.d.ts` file for Preact, and it does define the types for `h`. So this would appear to be a configuration problem.

Comment: I use latest create-react-app for my project setup.

Comment: This was fixed with the latest version of preact. `preact@10.0.0-beta.3` (or `preact@next`) contains the fix.